# Trying to report on my EKS clusters in AWS using python, with VScode, however I am getting errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Here is the code which I have written in VScode:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

def get_eks_cluster_info(region, cluster_name):
    eks_client = boto3.client('eks', region_name=region)
    cluster_info = eks_client.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)['cluster']
    capacity_info = eks_client.describe_fargate_profile(
        clusterName=cluster_name, fargateProfileName='fp-default')['fargateProfile']

    az_list = cluster_info['resourcesVpcConfig']['subnetIds']
    autoscaling_group_name = capacity_info['selectors'][0]['name']
    ec2_nodes_count = capacity_info['podExecutionRoleArn'].split('/')[-1].split(':')[-1]

    eks_version = cluster_info['version']
    capacity_type = capacity_info['selectors'][0]['type']
    utilized_capacity_gb = capacity_info['podExecutionRoleArn'].split('/')[-1].split(':')[-1]

    return {
        'Name of EKS managed cluster': cluster_name,
        'Region of EKS managed cluster': region,
        'AZ of EKS managed cluster': ', '.join(az_list),
        'No of EC2 nodes in EKS managed cluster': ec2_nodes_count,
        'Kubernetes version of EKS managed cluster': eks_version,
        'Utilized capacity in GB of EKS managed clusters': utilized_capacity_gb,
        'EKS managed cluster capacity type': capacity_type,
        'Autoscaling group of the EKS managed cluster': autoscaling_group_name
    }

def get_all_eks_clusters_info():
    regions = boto3.session.Session().get_available_regions('eks')
    all_clusters_info = []

    for region in regions:
        eks_client = boto3.client('eks', region_name=region)
        clusters = eks_client.list_clusters()['clusters']

        for cluster in clusters:
            cluster_info = get_eks_cluster_info(region, cluster)
            all_clusters_info.append(cluster_info)

    return all_clusters_info

all_clusters_info = get_all_eks_clusters_info()
df = pd.DataFrame(all_clusters_info)

file_name = 'eks_managed_node_clusters_report.xlsx'
df.to_excel(file_name, index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

When I run this with right credentials (I have checked, the same credentials run other customer AWS reporting scripts) it throws an error such as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\AWS\AWSManagedEKS.py", line 43, in <module>
    all_clusters_info = get_all_eks_clusters_info()
  File "c:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\AWS\AWSManagedEKS.py", line 35, in get_all_eks_clusters_info
    clusters = eks_client.list_clusters()['clusters']
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListClusters operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.**
```

I have checked my credentials and verified the service is running in AWS region,still getting error.
I also updated AWS credentials in VScode and refreshed the VScode, but still same error.
I was expecting the script to run and create a excel file as output.